# Code not recognising my generics (C#)

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I've got this program and I'm trying to pass parameters with generics, but I'm getting the following error for every TA and TB after public static List:

"The type or namespace name 'TA' or 'TB' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

I was using this tutorial on delegates and trying to make it work myself: http://www.velir.com/blog/index.php/2011/07/14/how-to-improve-code-reusability-using-c-delegates/

The layout honestly looks fine to me, though judging by the errors it seems to be an issue of scope? Feedback would be much appreciated.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  public class ListProcessor
{

   public delegate bool Acceptor<in TA>(TA obj);
   public delegate TB Processor<in TA, out TB>(TA obj);

   public static List<TB> ProcessList(
    List<TA> objects,
    Acceptor<TA> acceptor,
    Processor<TA, TB> processor)

{

    List<TB> newList = new List<TB>();
    foreach (TA obj in objects)
    {
        if(!acceptor(obj))
            {
                continue;
            }
        newList.Add(processor(obj));
    }

    return newList;     
}

public static void Main()
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();


    myList.Add("Carrot");
    myList.Add("Fox");
    myList.Add("albuquerque");

    List<string> resultStrings = ListProcessor.ProcessList(
        myList,
        str => !str.Contains("c"),
        str => str.Replace("a", "b"));

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the class declaration accordingly, to include `TA` and `TB`:

```
public class ListProcessor<TA, TB>
```

Looking at that referenced blog post, I'm not sure how their code could've compiled.